# ASTreeView to DataTable

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

In one of my projects I'm testing ASTreeView [Link](http://www.astreeview.com/astreeviewdemo/astreeviewdemo1.aspx).

I've successfully implemented it in my project. When I finish rearranging nodes I want to get data form treeview to DataTable, but project only allows export to XML.

Example of tree and generated XML:

[image: tree]

```
<astreeview>
   <astreeview-nodes>
        <astreeview-node node-text="node1" node-value="1" node-type="0" checked-state="2" open-state="0" selected="false" enable-edit-context-menu="true" enable-delete-context-menu="true" enable-add-context-menu="true" node-icon="" enable-drag-drop="true" enable-siblings="true" enable-children="true" enable-checkbox="true" enable-selection="true" enable-open-close="true" />
        <astreeview-node node-text="node2" node-value="2" node-type="0" checked-state="2" open-state="0" selected="false" enable-edit-context-menu="true" enable-delete-context-menu="true" enable-add-context-menu="true" node-icon="" enable-drag-drop="true" enable-siblings="true" enable-children="true" enable-checkbox="true" enable-selection="true" enable-open-close="true">
          <astreeview-nodes>
            <astreeview-node node-text="node2_1" node-value="4" node-type="0" checked-state="2" open-state="0" selected="false" enable-edit-context-menu="true" enable-delete-context-menu="true" enable-add-context-menu="true" node-icon="" enable-drag-drop="true" enable-siblings="true" enable-children="true" enable-checkbox="true" enable-selection="true" enable-open-close="true">
            </astreeview-node>
            <astreeview-node node-text="node2_2" node-value="8" node-type="0" checked-state="2" open-state="0" selected="false" enable-edit-context-menu="true" enable-delete-context-menu="true" enable-add-context-menu="true" node-icon="" enable-drag-drop="true" enable-siblings="true" enable-children="true" enable-checkbox="true" enable-selection="true" enable-open-close="true" />
          </astreeview-nodes>
        </astreeview-node>  <astreeview-node node-text="node3" node-value="3" node-type="0" checked-state="2" open-state="0" selected="false" enable-edit-context-menu="true" enable-delete-context-menu="true" enable-add-context-menu="true" node-icon="" enable-drag-drop="true" enable-siblings="true" enable-children="true" enable-checkbox="true" enable-selection="true" enable-open-close="true">
          <astreeview-nodes>
            <astreeview-node node-text="node3_1" node-value="32" node-type="0" checked-state="2" open-state="0" selected="false" enable-edit-context-menu="true" enable-delete-context-menu="true" enable-add-context-menu="true" node-icon="" enable-drag-drop="true" enable-siblings="true" enable-children="true" enable-checkbox="true" enable-selection="true" enable-open-close="true"/>
          </astreeview-nodes>
        </astreeview-node>
    </astreeview-nodes>
 </astreeview>
```

I need output in DataTable with following data for each node:
 node-text | node-value | node-parent.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your could read the xml with [DataTable.ReadXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.readxml(v=vs.110).aspx). But are you working with a DataSet or DataTable?

Comment: @Scrobi I've tried your suggestion and used DataSet.ReadXml(xml_string), which returns two DataTables. One with actual node data and second with node connections. Now with some work I'll be able to get all data in one DataTable, which is what I need. Thank you!